# How to store Jenkins job results and produce a summary report?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'd like to store custom job result data into some format (e.g. in XML) that Jenkins can read and produce the summary report on the job page (ideally in the form of table).

I'd like to know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at the [Summary Display plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Summary+Display+Plugin). Some more details about it (= quote from the linked page):

> ... allows an easy and fully customized build report display.
>
> Features
>
> - Allow a rich summary report visible from both project and build page
> - Reports must be written in an XML format according to the syntax described in section Syntax Description
> - This plugin allow the parsing of several XML files
> - Reports displayed are ordered according to the XML file names
> - Element displayed are based on

In general, the answer to such questions is usually found by searching the endless [Jenkins plugin index](https://plugins.jenkins.io/).